# Class 'PhpOffice\phpspreadsheet\src\PhpSpreadsheet\Spreadsheet' not found in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-7, phpoffice-phpspreadsheet

In my Laravel project I have used the `PhpOffice Spreadsheet` for downloading data as excel format from a datatable.

For doing that I need to add code in my controller, route and view.

**Controller**

I have used below namespaces in my controller

```
<?php

    namespace App\Http\Controllers;

    use PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Spreadsheet;
    use PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Writer\Xlsx;
    use PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Writer\Xls;
    use App\OfferCustomersDataTbl;

    public function export($type) {
        $offer_customer_data = OfferCustomersDataTbl::all();
        $spreadsheet = new Spreadsheet();
        $sheet = $spreadsheet->getActiveSheet();
        $sheet->setCellValue('A1', 'Id');
        $sheet->setCellValue('B1', 'Name');
        $sheet->setCellValue('C1', 'Email');
        $rows = 2;

        foreach($offer_customer_data as $empDetails){
            $sheet->setCellValue('A' . $rows, $empDetails['id']);
            $sheet->setCellValue('B' . $rows, $empDetails['name']);
            $sheet->setCellValue('C' . $rows, $empDetails['email']);
            $rows++;
        }

        $fileName = "emp.".$type;
        if($type == 'xlsx') {
        $writer = new Xlsx($spreadsheet);
        } else if($type == 'xls') {
        $writer = new Xls($spreadsheet);
        }
        $writer->save("export/".$fileName);
        header("Content-Type: application/vnd.ms-excel");
        return redirect(url('/')."/export/".$fileName);
    }
```

**Route**

```
Route::get('/export/{type}', 'OfferCustomersDataController@export');
```

**View**

```
<a href="{{ url('/') }}/export/xlsx" class="btn btn-info">Export to .xlsx</a>
```

But while I click to `Download as Excel` button for downloading it always gives an error

> Class 'PhpOffice\phpspreadsheet\src\PhpSpreadsheet\Spreadsheet' not
> found

But that `Spreadsheet` class is in that location I have checked several times.

Where is the problem I can't figure out.

Anybody help please? Thanks in advance

Comment: Please share more details. Where do you access the class with the given namespace?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In command line:
`composer require phpoffice/phpspreadsheet`

Then in the controller:

```
use PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Spreadsheet;
```

Use 'namespace' \ 'classname', not absolute link

Comment: now I use that
but still get the error `Class 'PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Spreadsheet' not found`

Comment: Did you use `composer require phpoffice/phpspreadsheet` in command line?

Comment: Yes that's the mistake. I solved it now. Please Make you answer to the point thus others can understand the solution and I will accept it